# Couldn't find Lesson with id=0 upon save on an object with has_and_belong_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-and-belongs-to-many

i have two objects
- material
- lesson

each material can have and belong to lesson; each lesson can have and belong to material.

in material_controller when i try to create

```
@material = Material.new(params[:material])

class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :lessons

   attr_accessible :content_type, :user_id, :lesson_ids
```

here is params

```
"material"=>{"content_type"=>"2",
"detail_content"=>"",
"user_id"=>"5",
"lesson_ids"=>"[]"},

create_table "lessons", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.string   "description"
t.integer  "course_id"
t.integer  "sequence"
t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
end

create_table "lessons_materials", :force => true do |t|
t.integer "lesson_id"
t.integer "material_id"
end

create_table "materials", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "content_type"
t.text     "detail_content"
t.text     "embedded_content"
t.string   "stored_file_name"
t.string   "stored_content_type"
t.integer  "stored_file_size"
t.datetime "stored_updated_at"
t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

Comment: even when lesson_ids have a valid value (e.g. [6]) i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think your `lesson_ids` param should be nil when you have no lesson associated, instead of being an array.

Comment: but what about when it has value, that doesn't work either. e.g lesson_ids = [6]

Comment: maybe we should also see your migrations for Material and Lesson

Comment: class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lessons

  attr_accessible :content_type, :detail_content, :embedded_content, :stored, :user_id, :lesson_ids
  has_attached_file :stored
  validates_presence_of :content_type, :user_id
  validates_inclusion_of :content_type, :in => 1..3